# Permission denied to get property HTMLDocument.body

Tags: javascript

I am doing a hidden http post in one page of my application which will login to another application via iframe.

In that iframe i am able to access certain functions of that application but however i encounter javascript Permission denied to get property HTMLDocument.body in that application when i try to save and update certain contents.

Any reasons for this weird behaviour and how to resolve this issue?

Yes i am referencing to another domain.
Is there anyway to work around this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Does you iframe reference another domain? If it does, you're probably hitting your browser's cross-site scripting defence.